# Can I copy a storyboard from one project to another project?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, storyboard

To reuse a storyboard, could I simply copy it from one project to another project (then make modification to the storyboard as required)?

Comment: You can reuse the storyboard from other projects. Copy to the current project and make it as main interface file

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes you can, just make sure they are selected as your main storyboards as per image below.

[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean by selected as your main storyboard? @Muhammad

Comment: This sorta works, but not really. When I click the tuxedo it does not let me Ctrl_Drag to connect items from the view to the controller. How can I fix it?

Comment: I had to open the storyboard XML in textedit and change the name of the "customClass" of the view controller.

Answer (score 15):

As @Muhammad said you can and it is very simple!

- You just have to drag the Storyboard file from one project to another and select all options (The same procedure as importing anything else!).
- Next, you just need to go to your project options by clicking on the project icon in the left upper side of project navigator.
- Then you just need to select this storyboard to be your storyboard and that's it.

Answer (score 9):

**Method 1**

Select the View Controller in the storyboard and press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy. Then press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste in the second storyboard. Check the document outline to see where it was pasted to.

**Method 2**

Right click the storyboard file in the Project Navigator and select Open As > Source Code. Scroll down the XML code until you find your View Controller. It will look something like this:

```
<!--My View Controller-->
<scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
    ...
</scene>
```

Copy this and paste it in the second project's storyboard file.

**Notes**

- You must also copy over the view controller swift file, of course, but the outlets shouldn't need to be reconnected.

Comment: Method 2 : This is the only thing working for me with XCode 11 - everything else makes it crash. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's simple. Just follow these steps:

1. Press cmd + D while selecting your desired storyboard scene. It will create a duplicate copy of your selected scene.
2. Press cmd + x to cut the scene from the existing project.
3. Press cmd + v into the storyboard section of the second project.

Cheers.