# Fixed bottom margin on UITableViewCell error caused by missing Rect tag

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to clarify my problem with you guys.

Recently I just upgrade my Xcode to newest Xcode 6.0.1 (Maverick OS) and Continue my project created by Xcode 5 without problem.

Until I create new UITableViewCell and put few View with Fixed bottom margin.. It got messed up when showed in Controller.. The View Y position with fixed bottom margin is messed up,
BUT... It's not happened with existing UITableViewCell that created on Xcode 5. It has View with fixed bottom margin too, but the error does't happened, it adjusting the position just fine when I resize the UITableViewCell.

Continue my debugging, I try to recreate the existing UITableViewCell and got the same error. After many testing, I decide to compare the view by opening the XIB in text editor and found a little difference that caused the error.

You can compare the result between 2 UITableViewCell bellow. The left picture is using existing UITableViewCell created on Xcode 5 ant the right one created on Xcode 6. "text 2" label Y position is messed up and go beyond cell height.

All setting is identical if you check on Xcode IB. But the text editor reveal more than that

[image: created with Xcode 5]
[image: created with Xcode 6]

Existing UITableViewCell (Xcode 5)

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="WSPostCell" rowHeight="100" id="PdK-a2-c84" customClass="WSPostCell">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="100"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
    <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="PdK-a2-c84" id="Y9d-Wv-BGf">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="99"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <subviews>
            <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 1" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="Vuu-pP-JOA">
                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="8" width="280" height="30"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="12"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
            <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 2" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="40X-YI-rMb">
                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="61" width="280" height="30"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="12"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
        </subviews>
    </tableViewCellContentView>
    <point key="canvasLocation" x="127" y="120"/>
</tableViewCell>
```

new UITableViewCell (Xcode6)

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="100" id="aI1-wx-nYK">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="100"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
    <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="aI1-wx-nYK" id="dNV-Xk-dVs">
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <subviews>
            <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 1" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="N8L-oO-ECr">
                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="280" height="30"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="12"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
            <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 2" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="IZV-oh-bet">
                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="61" width="280" height="30"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="12"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
        </subviews>
    </tableViewCellContentView>
    <point key="canvasLocation" x="511" y="120"/>
</tableViewCell>
```

If you look carefully, the second XML missing `<rect>` tag right after `<tableViewCellContentView>` tag.

```
 <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="99"/>
```

Is this a bug? or maybe I missing something that caused this horrible error? I'm disable Auto Layout and Size classes on File Inspector.

Comment: I had the same problem, I filled a bug report. It happens on both XCode 6 and XCode 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue in Xcode6. Moreover, I use dynamic cell and its content not visible. 
I tried with and without autolayouts and class sizing.

In storyboard I have the next: VC>View>TableView>Custom Cell(with identifier)>ContentView

I created very simple project - it loads VC with TableView like here:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"DataCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
return cell; }
```

But I can't even change background of the cell...Its a mess...I tried other ways using labels and tags, create subclasses but no hope. All my outlets are hooked up, all identifiers are set, I guess the cell appears outside the tableview and it caused by AutoLayout...

At the moment I have one hacking suggestion to solve the issue - you can import a storyboard with proper TableView from one of your previous projects. After that  all customization works.
[How to import storyboard.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20452737/4107938)

Nevertheless it is not a good practice and I hope somebody will find coding solution or Apple will fix the issue.