# Copied storyboard viewcontroller retains link to source

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

When I copy a view controller from the storyboard in one project to the storyboard in another, it is retaining a link to the original.

I copied the view controller according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13417473/59913).

Apple's [WiTap example iOS project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) has a Picker View Controller for connecting to a server. I copied the `Picker View Controller` from its storyboard and pasted it into the storyboard of [my project](https://github.com/wanderingstan/AppleFaceDetection). It shows up fine, but now when I hover over a connected UILabel (e.g. `connectView` in my code it highlights in *both* projects and shows it linked to both storyboards!

[image: Xcode screenshot showing 2 storyboards connected to labe]

Furthermore, when the view controller is displayed, I get an error suggesting that the UILabel is not on the storyboard at all.

`2017-06-22 16:15:25.075626-0600 VisionDetection[2565:2403974] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewController 0x103a0fc50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key connectView.'`

I suspect Xcode is getting confused about connecting the UI elements in my code with the copied storyboard, but I can't figure out what's wrong.